# "a great many processes"

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article, determiners

> Yet **a great many processes** depending on such research are sought for with complete secrecy until the stage at which patents can be taken out. (J.D. Bernal "Secrecy in Industry," in L.G. Alexander, *New Concept English*, Book 4; emphasis mine)

How is the phrase "a great many processes" grammatical? Shouldn't one use the indefinite article "a" only before a singular noun (while here it is the plural "processes")?

Answer (score 1):

**a good (or great) many** means **a large number of sth**

> e.g. there were a great many questions about the problem.

Here **great many processes** is being treated as a single entity and for this entity indefinite article **a is used**

Comment: (1) I understand that "a great many" can mean "a large number of something" - but that's beside the point: If you substitute "a large number of something" for "a great many" here, the sentence will read (presumably the "something" is "processes"): "Yet a large number of processes processes [sic] depending on such research are sought for ..." Yes, "processes" is repeated! It appears the phrase "a great many" here is not used as a noun-type component of the sentence but an adjective-type component that describes "processes.“ (2) Is there any justification for treating "processes" as a single...

Comment: ...entity? What other situations does this rule extend to?

Comment: "A great many processes" is singular because it refers to the single group which contains many processes. It is many things being considered together and referred to as a single thing. You're right about "a great many" being an adjective phrase that modifies "processes".